# Log4Net: Rotating logs file name

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have the following log4net configuration:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\\logs\\ListingsIngestService-log-file.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Currently this is making the log's file name to come out like this:

- ListingsIngestService-log-file.log <- Current date Log
- ListingsIngestservice.log-file.log.20140611.log <- Log from an old date.

Is there a way to remove the first ".log" occurrence from the old logs file names? If I take it out from the value parameter of the file tag then the first log won't have a ".log" extension and I need it for another utility that runs on the log directory.

Answer (score 2):

The last log comes from:"

```
<datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
```

If you remove the '.log'

```
<datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd" />
```

you will generate log files like ListingsIngestservice.log-file.log.20140611